# Authorization on a per-route basis (Protected Routes) with Apollo for local state management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, apollo, apollo-client

I am using react-router-dom, typescript, react, and Apollo graphql-generator & client.

I am looking to handle 4 scenarios:

1. Route open to logged-in and logged-out users
2. Route open to logged-in users only
3. Route open to logged-out users only
4. Route open to users that are member of a group policy stored on the db

**I don't want to manage state via props, but rather use a Redux-like approach to state-management, using something in Apollo Client.**

The closest I have gotten so far is via Reactive Variables (see code below).

However, I would rather like to avoid using them, and stick with Apollo queries.

We have a query in our GraphQL that returns the current logged-in user, however, I can't seem to have the query run and update at time of login, so that it can be used in checking routes. That is unless I create a state in the App file, and inject it into the Login component for it to update it. Then, when Login redirects to a new route, the  component in the App file, with the userState that was just updated, can check the userState for authorizing the route where Login redirected to.

As I said above, though, I want to avoid passing around state through props.

The current implementation is based on this: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { HashRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  makeVar,
} from '@apollo/client'

// -------------------------- client.js -------------------------------------------------
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

// set userVar initially to null, so if !null then logged in
export const userVar = makeVar(null)

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  cache
});


// --------------------------- routes.js ------------------------------------------------
const ROUTES = {
  HOME: '/',          // Only accessible by logged-in users
  LOGIN: '/login',    // Only accessible by users NOT logged-in
  ABOUT: '/about',    // Accessible by all logged-in / and not logged-in users
  NOTFOUND: '/notFound',
}

const { PUBLIC, AUTH, GUEST } = {
  PUBLIC: 0,
  AUTH: 1,
  GUEST: 2,
}

const AuthRoute = props => {
  const { path, restrictTo, redirectPath, ...routeProps } = props
  console.log("Inside AuthRoute")
  console.table({path, restrictTo, redirectPath, ...routeProps})
  const isAuthorized = to => {
    const authOnly = !!(userVar() ?? false)
    console.log(`authOnly = ${ authOnly }`)
    console.log(`to = ${ to }`)

    const allowAll = true

    switch (to) {
      case PUBLIC:
        console.log(`PUBLIC --> isAuthorized --> allowAll = ${ allowAll }`)
        return allowAll
      case AUTH:
        console.log(`AUTH --> isAuthorized --> authOnly = ${ authOnly }`)
        return authOnly
      case GUEST:
        console.log(`GUEST --> isAuthorized --> !authOnly = ${ !authOnly }`)
        return !authOnly
    }
  }

  if (isAuthorized(restrictTo)) {
    console.log(`Authorized -- Routing to ${ path }`)
    console.log(`Authorized -- routeProps = `)
    console.table({...routeProps})

    return <Route {...routeProps} />
  } else {
    console.log(`--> NOT Authorized -- Redirecting to ${ redirectPath }`)
    return <Redirect to={ redirectPath } />
  }
}


// ------------------------   home.js  -----------------------------------------
const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const signOut = () => {
    // Do auth reset here
    userVar(null) //reset global state to logged-out
    history.push(ROUTES.LOGIN)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home - Private Page</h1>
      <button  onClick={ signOut }>Sign Out</button>
    </div>
  )
}


// ------------------------   about.js  -----------------------------------------
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About - Public Page</h1>
    </div>
  )
}


// ------------------------   notfound.js  -----------------------------------------
const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>404 - Public Page</h1>
    </div>
  )
}


// ------------------------   login.js  -----------------------------------------
const Login = ({onSubmit}) => {
  console.log(`--> Inside Login`)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory()

  const onLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //Do email/password auth here
    userVar(email) //Set global state to logged-in
    history.push(ROUTES.HOME)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>LOGIN</h1>
      <form onSubmit={ onLogin }>
        <label for="uemail"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Email"
          name="uemail"
          value={ email }
          onChange={ (e) => setEmail( e.target.value ) }
          required
        />
        <label for="upassword"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          name="upassword"
          value={ password }
          onChange={ (e) => setPassword( e.target.value ) }
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}


// ------------------------   index.js   ---------------------------------------------
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
      </ApolloProvider>
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
)


// ------------------------   App.js   ---------------------------------------------
function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <AuthRoute exact
          path={ROUTES.HOME}
          restrictTo={AUTH}
          redirectPath={ROUTES.LOGIN}
      >
        <Home />
      </AuthRoute>

      <AuthRoute
        path={ROUTES.LOGIN}
        restrictTo={GUEST}
        redirectPath={ROUTES.HOME}
      >
        <Login />
      </AuthRoute>

      <AuthRoute
        path={ROUTES.ABOUT}
        restrictTo={PUBLIC}
        redirectPath={ROUTES.ABOUT}
      >
        <About />
      </AuthRoute>

      <AuthRoute
        path={ROUTES.NOTFOUND}
        restrictTo={PUBLIC}
        redirectPath={ROUTES.NOTFOUND}
      >
        <NotFound />
      </AuthRoute>

      // Catch-all Route -- could send to 404 if you want
      <Route>
        <Redirect to={ROUTES.NOTFOUND} />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@apollo/client@3.3.2/apollo-client.cjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.2.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.2.0/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I know this is a self-answer, but your question is too broad, is missing a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and is missing a formal declaration and details of any specific issue. It reads more as a code writing service request, which is something that Stackoverflow is not, and is very off-topic.

Comment: That's a fair comment. If this wasn't a self-answer I would re-write. However, as the code in my answer provides full detail of what I'm trying to achieve, I feel it can be left as is. The only reason I'm even posting is to see if anyone can improve on my solution.

Comment: If you've working code and you're looking for something more of a code review then I suggest https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware codereview.stack... existed.

Comment: I have fixed up the question and answer to better match the guidelines provided. Thank you for the constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was to use LazyQuery from Apollo, which is a query that can actually be used in call-backs (including hooks, etc.).

We are using Apollo code-gen for GraphQL, and after digging into the generated code, I did notice that it generated both getCurrentUserQuery, and getCurrentUser**Lazy**Query.

Also, while this solution does pass a prop, it is an immutable use of it that only goes one layer deep, and doesn't get passed around any further, so I felt it was a decent compromise since I can call up the Apollo Query for current user in other places, when I need it.

Therefore, I got rid of the entire AuthRoute / ProtectedRoute component, and just did as follows (relevant code only):

```js
// In App.tsx

// other code is around the code contained here... this is just a snippet

const [getUser, { data }] = useGetCurrentUserLazyQuery({})

  let location = useLocation()

  useAsyncEffect(     // Also works with useEffect, but Async cuts down on calls
    async isMounted => {
      await getUser()
      if (!isMounted()) return
    },
    [location]
  )
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppRoutes email={data?.getCurrentUser?.email} />
    </div>
  )
  
  
  
  // In AppRoutes.tsx
  // other code is around the code contained here... this is just a snippet
  // email prop type declaration is ... email: string | undefined
  const { email } = props
  const isLoggedIn = !!(email ?? false)
  
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN}>
          {isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to={ROUTES.HOME} /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <Route path={ROUTES.HOME}>
          {!isLoggedIn ? (
            <Redirect to={ROUTES.LOGIN} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to={DEFAULT_PATH} />
          )}
        </Route>
        )
```